# DateFNS closestIndexTo returns NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, date-fns

I need to get the closest date from an array of dates with DateFNS v.2.0.1 [closestIndexTo](https://date-fns.org/v2.0.1/docs/closestIndexTo). I'm currently getting NaN returned. What am I missing here?

```
(val = 2019-09-01) 
(arrDates = 2019-09-01,2019-09-03,2019-09-03,2019-09-04,2019-09-05,2019-09-05,2019-09-23,2019-10-01,2019-11-18)

getClosestToDate(val,arr) {
  var arrDates = [_.map(arr, 'date')]
  var closestDate = closestIndexTo(parseISO(val), arrDates)
  return closestDate
},
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nearest-date using it,maybe not your want but it simple and successful get closest date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically dates should be strings in first place. Next probably incorrect place is where you use `[_.map(arr, 'date')]` which actually place result of map into array making it double array. Also in order to parse `arr` into `Date` objects you need map arr values to `parseISO` function. So following code should work

```
var closestIndexTo = require('date-fns/closestIndexTo')
var parseISO = require('date-fns/parseISO')
var _ = require('lodash')

val = "2019-10-04"
arrDates = ["2019-09-01","2019-09-03","2019-09-03","2019-09-04","2019-09-05","2019-09-05","2019-09-23","2019-10-01","2019-11-18"]

function getClosestToDate(val, arr) {
  var arrDates = _.map(arr, (a) => parseISO(a))
  var closestDate = closestIndexTo(parseISO(val), arrDates)
  return closestDate
}

console.log("result", getClosestToDate(val, arrDates))
```

Here is link to [repl](https://repl.it/repls/AquamarineUnwittingGraphics)

Comment: Just tested it, return NaN for me. arrDates in console.log returns Invalid Date. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you placed `"` around your arrDates entiries? On initialization step

Comment: How do I add them?

Comment: @Tom please take a look at code I've provided. There is `arrDates` initialized where each element of array is placed like `"2019-09-01"`. Also you can click on link at the very bottom that should lead you to sandbox with this code.